# An empty Post request AJAX + Spring Boot arrives

Tags: json, ajax, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

On the front end, there is this code:

```
$("#add_button").click(function() {
    console.log("The button has been pressed");
    var genre = {
        name: $("#genre_name").val(),
        description: $("#genre_desc").val()
    };
            
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save_genre",
    data: JSON.stringify(genre),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Genre successfully created:", response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error("An error occurred while creating the genre:", error);
    }
});
```

In it, by pressing a button, we read data from two forms, create an object, serialize it into JSON format and send a POST request to the server at the URL "/save_genre".

In turn, on the server side, we accept and write to the database:

```
@RestController
public class AddGenreRestController {

    @Autowired
    private GenreRepository GenreRepository;

    @PostMapping("/save_genre")
    public Genres addGenre(@RequestBody Genres genre) {
        System.out.println("Genre = " + genre.GetName());
        return GenreRepository.save(genre);
    }
}
```

In response to the line: `System.out.println("Genre = " + genre.GetName());` the value `Genre = null` is printed to the console. A new record is created in the table, but the fields are also set to `NULL`.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

My "Generes" class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Genres")
public class Genres {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long ID;

    private String name;

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;

    public Genres() {

    }

    public Long GetID() { return ID; }
    public void SetID(Long ID) { this.ID = ID; }
    public String GetName() { return name; }
    public void SetName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String GetDescription () { return description; }
    public void SetDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
}
```

Comment: please add the Genres class

Comment: @Mark Stroebel, Added

Comment: add a constructor to your Genres class, default one with params and one without params, also methods in `Java is case-sensitive` rename your get and set methods by convention, your `@RequestBody` work with these methods. Example `GetName()` should be `getName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getter/setter names are not matching bean conventions, change to lowercase first letter or use Jackson annotations to mark it

```
public String getName() { return name; }
public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations